# Javascript Sharepoint Comparar campo Data com Data Hoje

Tags: javascript, data, sharepoint

Eu tenho uma lista no sharepoint com o código abaixo: 
Eu preciso comparar a data do campo "Data_x0020_de_x0020_Entrega" com o data atual "hoje", mas pelo código abaixo está comparando apenas o primeiro dígito da data, por exemplo, se hoje É 03/03/2017 e o campo "Data_x0020_de_x0020_Entrega" está em 20/02/2017 está comparando apenas os primeiros dígitos no caso, '03' com '20'

Como faço para comparar as duas datas?

```
(function () {
  var fieldCtx = {};


  fieldCtx.Templates = {};
  fieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "Progress": {
        "View": ProgressFieldViewTemplate
    }
  };

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldCtx);
})();

function ProgressFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {

  var _statusValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Data_x0020_de_x0020_Entrega;
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
  } 

  if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
  } 

  today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

  if (_statusValue > today)
  {
    return "<img src='https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/sites/intralogo/SiteAssets/icons/Green.png'/>";
  }
  else if (_statusValue == today)
  {
    return "<img src='https://xxxxxxxxxx/sites/intralogo/SiteAssets/icons/Yellow.png'/>";
  } 
  else if (_statusValue < today)
  {
    return "<img src='https://xxxxxxxxx/sites/intralogo/SiteAssets/icons/Red.png'/>";
  }   
}
```

Comment: voce esta comparando duas strings, voce deveria comparar dois objetos `Date`

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso vá te ajudar, voce deve pegar a sua data, transformar num objeto `Date` javscript e ai sim comparar.

Como você quer desconsiderar as horas, foi necessário criar uma variavel Date a partir do valor da data atual para poder fazer a comparacao correta.

segue codigo abaixo:

```js
function ProgressFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {
  var dateStr = ctx.CurrentItem.Data_x0020_de_x0020_Entrega;

  var dt = new Date(parseInt(dateStr.substr(6,4)) 
                  , parseInt(dateStr.substr(3,2)) -1 
                  , parseInt(dateStr.substr(0,2)));
  var today = new Date();

  today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

  if(dt < today){
    return "<img src='https://xxxxxxxxx/sites/intralogo/SiteAssets/icons/Red.png'/>";
  } else if ( dt > today ){
    return "<img src='https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/sites/intralogo/SiteAssets/icons/Green.png'/>";
  }else {
    return "<img src='https://xxxxxxxxxx/sites/intralogo/SiteAssets/icons/Yellow.png'/>";
  }
}
```